# Oracle: update non-unique field

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

I need to update a non-unique field. I have a table tbl:

```
create table tbl (A number(5));
```

Values in tbl: 1, 2, 2, 2 .. 2.

I need to replace all 2 with new non-unique values

New values: 1, 100, 101, 102, 103 .. 
I wrote:

```
DECLARE
    sql_stmt VARCHAR2(500);
   cursor curs is 
        select A from tbl group by A having count(*)>1;
   l_row curs%ROWTYPE;
   i number(5);
   new_mail VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  i:=100;
  open curs;
  loop
    fetch curs into l_row;
    exit when curs%notfound; 
    SQL_STMT := 'update tbl set a='||i||' where a='||l_row.A;
    i:=i+1;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
  end loop;
  close curs;
END;
/
```

But I got:

```
         A
----------
         1
       100
       ...
       100
```

What can be wrong? Why doesn't the loop work?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your code is supposed to do. Can you add the contents of the table before and what you expect afterwards?

Comment: (a) What are you expecting as output?  (b) Are you running into problems with not being able to see your own updates under Oracle's MVCC?

Comment: Jonathan Leffler,a) i want replace non-unique field with new values: 1, 100,101,102... b) i++ doenst work, tbl updated, but not correct

Comment: But your cursor is grouping by `A`, so you'll get one row for each unique value, and update all instances of that value to the *same* value of `i`. Run that select on its own to see what it returns.

Comment: Alex Poole, I know, but its not really important for me now.

Comment: Not really important? It's the crux of why it's not doing what you want *8-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about

```
update tbl
set a = 100 + rownum 
where a in (
    select a 
    from    tbl 
    group by a
    having count(*) > 1 )
```

the subquery finds duplicated A fields and the update gives them the unique identifier starting from 100. (you got other problems here like , what if id 100, 101.... already exists ).

first rule of PLSQL says that **what ever you can do with SQL always do with SQL**. writing straight up `for` `loop` cause allot of context switches between the sql and pl/sql engine. even if oracle automatically converts this to a bulk statement (10g<) it will still be faster with pure SQL.

Comment: Agreed, it should be done in SQL if possible, I'd meant to say that in my answer. You're missing a `group by` clause though *8-)

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor gets one row per unique value of `A`:

```
select A from tbl group by A having count(*)>1;
```

You need to get all the distinct rows that match those values. One way is to do this:

```
select a, r from (
    select a, rowid as r, count(*) over (partition by a) as c
    from tbl
) where c > 1;
```

... and then use the `rowid` values to do the update. I'm not sure why you're using dynamic SQL as it is not at all necessary, and you can simplify (IMO) the loop:

```
declare
    i number(5);
begin
    i:=100;
    for l_row in (
        select a, r from (
            select a, rowid as r, count(*) over (partition by a) as c
            from tbl
        ) where c > 1) loop
        update tbl set a=i where rowid = l_row.r;
        i:=i+1;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

---

I've kept this as PL/SQL to show what was wrong with what you were attempting, but @haki is quite correct, you should (and can) [do this in plain SQL if at all possible](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5500485045890). Even if you need it to be PL/SQL because you're doing other work in the loop (as the `new_mail` field might suggest) then you might be able to still do a single update within the procedure, rather than one update per iteration around the loop.